# Cannot find recompiled version of my apk

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, apktool

After typing this command:

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\apktool>apktool b MyAPK myapk-new.apk
```

After that i recive this logs

```
I: Using Apktool 2.3.3
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building apk file...
I: Copying unknown files/dir...
I: Built apk...
```

The problem is that i cannot find the bulit apk anywhere. I have also used

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\apktool>apktool b MyAPK myapk-new.apk--frame-path C:\Users\PC\Desktop\apktool
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/) if you type:

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\apktool>apktool b MyAPK
```

your .apk will be in MyAPK/dist

Comment: On Ubuntu it can be found under 'dist' directory